# I cant resolve this error: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-imaging-library

Error:
/bin/python3.9 /home/joao/Documents/GitHub/TP-MULT/programa/functions.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joao/Documents/GitHub/TP-MULT/programa/functions.py", line 2, in 
from PIL import Image
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 69, in 
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/**init**.py)

And i'm 100% that i installed this library, system says:
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.4.0)

I dont know why I'm steel with this problem...
Tanks for your attention,
Have a great day.

[The error stands for line 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRIlO.png)

[My python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIFZo.png)

[My environment says that i already have pillow....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5kOK.png)

Comment: Please share a minimal example of code that causes this error and explain a bit more about your setup. Version of Python, how do you manage your (virtual) environment, what packages installed, OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In python, when a variable, function or method has a single underscore before its name (like the "_imaging" you're trying to import)  these are private to where they are declared. They can still be called(but not normally).

That's the limit to all I can say with the information you've provided.